# Override default JSON parsing for POST request in Play Framework

Tags: java, json, playframework

I do use the great advantage of `overriding` the `onError` method in `Global.java` to control all exception handling in my Play application. Now, when I do a `POST reques`t to my `API` defining its `Content-Type` as `application/json` and using a `malformatted JSON array`, I'll get a `Bad Request For request 'POST /api/something' [Invalid Json]` on the client side but can't override this by my own `onError` function as it obviously does not provoke a `JsonParsingException` or alike.

Does anybody know how I can replace the HTML Bad request page by, let's say my own `JSON` array with an error message? That would help me a lot!

Thanks in advance, Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play does obviously not throw an exception when malformatted JSON arrays are posted.
I decided to use the `onBadRequest` method as I did not find a way to intercept Play's default behaviour in order to throw an exception.